# I have to click a button twice for an event handler to fire javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click

I am building a webpage to record the scores of a game I'm playing. I have a function called recordScores that is supposed to run when the user clicks a specific button.  What is happening is I have to click the button twice in order for the event to trigger and the function.  The function itself works properly

I originally had my html set up using onclick="recordScores()", but it had the same result.  Due to suggestions I found here I changed it to using an event handler.

HTML: (Spaces added before the opening < so the code shows properly)

```
   Enter Score:< input type="text" id="scoreInputBox">
        <button id="submitScore">Submit< /button>
```

Javascript:

```
// Event Handler
document.getElementById("submitScore").addEventListener("click", 
recordScore);

Function:
// Allows the user to enter in a score
function recordScore(){

    // First get the value of the person selected from the dropdown
    var userDropdown = document.getElementById('playerNameDropdown');

    // Get the userId, which is the index value used in the scores array
    var userId = userDropdown.options[userDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    // Get the user entered score
    var userScore = document.getElementById('scoreInputBox').value;

    var score = parseInt(userScore);

    // Record the score in the array
    scoreArray[userId][round] = score;

    if (turnCounter == numPlayers) {
        round++;
        turnCounter = 1;
        score = 0;
        addTableRow();
        addNewScoreArrayValues();
    } else {
        turnCounter++;
        score = 0;
    }

    // For testing.  Remove when it displays in the browser
   // displayArray();
    displayScores();
    displayTotalScores();
}
```

Expected result is the first time the user clicks the "Submit" button, the event handler is triggered, and the recordScore() function runs.

Comment: provide the whole codes

Answer (score 0):

this problem may occur as your button type is not submit. Try this.

```
 <button type='submit' id="submitScore">Submit </button>
```

Comment: No luck.  I've updated my html with the same result.  Thank you though for catching one of my mistakes.